# Higher Education Graduations by U.S. County

Tags: usa, education

The U.S. Census provides [educational attainment statistics](https://www.census.gov/topics/education/educational-attainment.html) at county-level. This is a break-down of local population by level of educational attainment (high school, bachelor, etc.).

I am looking for historical (since 2000) annual county-level (or Metropolitan Statistical Area-level) enrollment/graduations from higher education institutions.

Comment: Are you asking for it to be parsed by the college's location? Because IPEDS data, https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/Home/UseTheData, has the zip code of each school along with enrollment and graduation stats. You could geocode the county from there.

Comment: @wirefire Thank you! This looks like what I need, but the site is a mess to navigate. I assume what I need is under the "Compare Institutions" heading. For historical data, it looks like I should select the list of (US) institutions and then my variables (geo and degrees for graduations) for each collection year by turn. That means 15 downloads for 15 years. Correct? (assuming that multi-year variables for institutions of 2015 do not include values for institutions of previous years which are missing in 2015 collected data, for any reason)

Comment: I agree, this site is a mess. I have tried to do similar things before and just gotten lost in the weeds. You could also try the custom data downloads, for what it's worth. https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/InstitutionByName.aspx